# Attributing dimension to a raw vector in R

Tags: r, file, byte

I'm experiencing problems when attributing dimensions to a raw vector in R. I'm managing a very large file, so I help you understand the limits to provide a complete reproducible code here... my file brings genomic data.

So, I first set the number of bytes. Such number is based on the size of a vector of individuals.

```
nids <- length(ids); # ids is a vector with 310 individuals;
nids
> [1] 310

nbytes <- ceiling(nids/4) # number of bytes = 78
nbytes
> [1] 78
```

Then, I scan from a file data I'm interested in...

```
rdta <- scan(file=file,what=raw(),quiet=TRUE)
> str(rdta)
 raw [1:16928790] 00 00 00 00 ...
```

Next, I try to attribute dimensions to this raw vector. But first, I get the number of snp markers I need to read from my file. The rdta vector has just read this information.

```
nsnps <- 54609
dim(rdta) <- c(nbytes,nsnps)
```

Then, I get this error:

```
Error in dim(rdta) <- c(nbytes, nsnps) : 
  dims [product 4259502] do not match the length of object [16928790]
```

Ok, I know this is a matter of wrong dimensions. However, I cannot see where the problem is here. Does anyone have a clue on this? It seems that nsnps is bigger than nbytes...

Comment: The error is self-explanatory, so something has to be wrong with either `nsnps` or `nbytes`.

Comment: of course is self-explanatory! I said that "matter of wrong dimensions". However, I aks if you would have any clue on how to solve this. I think nbytes are wrong. Is this a problem with my file? do I need more bytes than what nbytes is defining.... ??

Comment: Well, the length of your file (16928790) can be represented as a product of 310 and 54609, so my wild guess that you need to set `nbytes <- nids`.

Comment: well, thanks to your comment I thought something here! Actually the 16928790 number is for the whole dataset (310 individuals and 54609 snps). I need an array where each column has bytes for only one snp for all the 310 animals. So, each snp (column) should need 78bytes. Probably the issue here is with scan() and file. scan() is reading all rows of my .txt file, when it should read only one row (each row has observations for 310 animals)...

Comment: nope, I've just tested. This is not the problem....